# Can child component only change parent state if event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to understand how a child component can change its parents' state and realize that the only examples in which I am able to successfully accomplish this (and the only examples I see online) deal with a callback being passed from a parent to a child that is then linked to an event (onClick, onChange etc..) in the child.  Thus, can a child component only change it's parents' state if the child uses an event to call the inherited callback?

This works:

```js
class Child extends React.Component{
  handleClick(){
    console.log('pressed')
    this.props.message('Hi mom!')
  }
  render(){
    return (<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Prese Me</button>)
  }
};

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      messageFromChild: '',
    }
    this.callBackFromParent = this.callBackFromParent.bind(this);
  }
  
  callBackFromParent(dataFromChild){
    this.setState({messageFromChild: dataFromChild})
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Message from Child is:</h2>
        <h2>{this.state.messageFromChild}</h2>
        
        <Child message={this.callBackFromParent}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But this leads to in infinite loop:

```js
class Child extends React.Component{
  render(){
    this.props.message('Hi Mom')
    return(
      <h2>Dummy message from child</h2>
    )
  }
};

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      messageFromChild: '',
    }
    this.callBackFromParent = this.callBackFromParent.bind(this);
  }
  
  callBackFromParent(dataFromChild){
    this.setState({messageFromChild: dataFromChild})
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Message from Child is:</h2>
        <h2>{this.state.messageFromChild}</h2>
        
        <Child message={this.callBackFromParent}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use the functions as event handlers, but calling it directly on render would cause the parent component to `setState` immediately, which would result in another render of the `Child` component, and the loop continues. You could e.g. set a timeout in `componentDidMount` of the `Child` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use the functions as event handlers, but calling it directly on render would cause the parent component to `setState` immediately, which would result in another render of the `Child` component, and the loop continues. You could e.g. set a timeout in `componentDidMount` of the `Child` and it will work fine.